# PHP switch function doesn't recognize "less than 0"

Tags: php

```
$bytes = 0;
switch($bytes){
    case $bytes == 0:
        echo 'Equal to 0.';
    break;
    case $bytes < 0:
        echo 'Less than 0.';
    break;
}
```

This outputs "Less than 0."

Why?

Comment: That is not how switch works ..

Comment: It reads $bytes == 0 as "true" and $bytes < 0 as "false".. and since $bytes is 0, it matches 0 with false. I need a break...

Comment: Yes, that's a nice answer .. consider adding it below (as it *explains* the behavior) :)

Comment: @nick: Yep, that's exactly what's going on.  We've all made mistakes like that :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`switch` statements don't work like that.  When checking each `case`, the value is compared to the `case` value (using `==`).

So, PHP is doing:

- Does `$bytes == ($bytes == 0)`?  Which is: `$bytes == (true)`.  This is `false`, so it's skipped.
- Does `$bytes == ($bytes < 0)`?  Which is: `$bytes == (false)`.  This is `true`, so it runs that block.

You need to use an `if/else` here.

```
$bytes = 0;
if($bytes == 0){
    echo 'Equal to 0.';
}
elseif($bytes < 0){
    echo 'Less than 0.';
}
```

Comment: I figured case is equivalent to IF expression==true, guess i was wrong

Comment: `case` is equivalent to if `$value == expression`.

Comment: To elaborate on this:
The case statement evaluates the given value and compares the selected variable against it.  In this case, `$bytes == 0` is true (value of `1`), which isn't equal to `$bytes`.  Then it tries `$bytes < 0` which is false (value of `0`), hence executing the block.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but there's another way of using switch :) I found it on SitePoint!

```
switch (true) {

    case $bytes == 0:      // result of this expression must be boolean
        echo 'Equal to 0.';
    break;

    case $bytes < 0:     // result also must be boolean
        echo 'Less than 0.';
    break;

    default:
}
```

Explanation: if `true == ($bytes == 0)` or if `true == ($bytes > 0)` or `default:`
You can use `switch (false) {}` if you have many falsy results instead of `x != y`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use operators in your switch statements. It actually should be:

```
$bytes = 0;
switch($bytes){
    case 0:
        echo 'Equal to 0.';
    break;
    default:
        echo 'Something else';
    break;
}
```

Have a look at the full documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Why does your sample result in 'less than zero'? Easy question:
($bytes < 0) evaluates to false, since it isn't. False is equivalent to 0 so it matches $bytes and falls into that case.

If you need to match certain ranges you are bound to use if-else-constructs.